# Implicit conversion paradox

Tags: scala

If I try to define an implicit conversion for a primitive type, then it doesn't seem to work. E.g.:

```
implicit def globalIntToString(a: Int) : String = { a.toString() + "globalhi" }
1.toInt + "hi"
```

The above will still return simply "1hi" as the result.

However, it seems that if I parameterize a class or a def and then pass in the implicit for the parametrized case, then it seems to work. Does anyone know what the reasons are? E.g. does this have something to do with boxing/unboxing of primtives (e.g., parameterized primitives are boxed)? Does implicit only work with reference types and not primitive types?

```
class typeConv[T] { implicit def tToStr(a: T) : String = { a.toString() + "hi" } }
class t[K](a: K)(tc : typeConv[K]) { import tc._; println(a + "cool"); println(1.toInt + "cool" ) }
new t(1)(new typeConv[Int])
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few subtle things going on here. @yan has already explained the core issue - I'll try to add some more specific information.

As noted, `1.toInt + "hi"` will never use any implicit conversion because Scala `Int` class actually has a method `+` that takes a `String` parameter. The compiler will look for an implicit view only when it can't find matching member in the original type.

A little more complicated stuff is happening inside your `t` class. Scalac will look for implicit conversion from a generic type `K` to any type that has a `+` method that takes a `String` parameter. There will be two candidates for such a conversion: your own `tc.tToStr` and Scala built-in `scala.Predef.any2stringadd`.

Normally, `any2stringadd` would be used, but in your example, your own conversion is used. Why does it have precedence over `any2stringadd`?

During implicit search, `tc.tToStr` is seen as a function of type `K => String`, while `any2stringadd` is seen as a function of type `Any => StringAdd`. My guess is that `K => String` is seen by the compiler as a *more specific* conversion than `Any => StringAdd`, but someone would have to confirm it with a proper reference to Scala Language Specification.

As you can see, defining such conversions may cause you a lot of strange behaviour. I'd definitely say that introducing an implicit conversion to a `String` is asking for trouble.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm actually working on more complicated implicit cases (not the String conversion case) where parameterized Int and actually Int seem to be following different logic. It's still confusing as hell.

Answer (score 2):

This happens because Scala defines a `+` operator on the Int type that takes a String and does not need to resolve an implicit conversion. Also, converting to `String` is usually a bad idea, as you'd generally have a custom, one-off type that would define the methods you're trying to add.

Comment: But the implicit conversion works with the parameterized Int case. And I'm just using String as an example. I'd like to know the exact mechanics of how implicit conversions are applied.